# Show images from table in a grid

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have this code in my php file.

```
<?php
 session_start();   
 include "connection.php";

 $qry="SELECT ServiceIcon FROM Services LEFT JOIN UserServices ON UserServices.ServiceID=Services.ServiceID WHERE UserServices.UserID=$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]";
 $result=mysql_query($qry);

 header("Content-type: image/png");
 echo mysql_result($result,0);
 ?>
```

However, this displays the images from my table on top of eachother. I want them arranged three in a row. How can I do this?

Comment: This script gives an image as result? What is it exacly you're trying to do? Do you want more of these images on a page next to each other (e.g. with CSS), or do you want multiple icons on one image?

Comment: I want it to look like this for example: http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/lordalea/lordalea1108/lordalea110800010/10128358-hand-drawn-school-icons-isolated-on-school-grid.jpg

Comment: Also, your WHERE clause contradicts your OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Assign them a class/id in CSS then in CSS preposition each one with coordinates